# removing newsletter & paypal layouts in home page

Tags: magento-1.8, newsletter

How can I remove blocks (newsletter,compare) in **home page only** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the `cms_index_index` page handle* in your `local.xml`

For example for newsletter and compare, when using a standard Magento theme the `local.xml` would need something like this:

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="left">
      <remove name="left.newsletter"/>
   </reference>
   <reference name="right">
      <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Optionally you can also add this in the CMS page custom `layout field` in the backend.

If you use a custom theme you will need to find the name of the block that holds the subscription form and remove that one.

**credits to Marius for pointing that one out to me*

Comment: check this link it's reference of all [magneto default block][1] name that can you remove any time. http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/05/remove-default-magneto-block-like-news.html